# How to read a file that has around 600K rows into google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a csv file which has around 600k rows but when i uploaded it into the google colab and check the number of rows its only around 21k .

train_transaction_data =pd.read_csv('train_transaction.csv' )

Comment: Can you tell us how are you displaying the number of rows of your imported csv file?

Comment: using train_transaction_data.shape.

Comment: Some problematic data might be skipped; what kind of data is inside your csv?

Comment: It has both categorical and numeric values  along with NA's.

Comment: Did you checked if the problem was from google colab by loading the CSV in a local python environment? Also, did you checked before which value the loading is stopping?